# How can I show visual studio process created using EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process-explorer

I have an app that can help to explore, generate and open visual studio projects. I'm creating the visual studio process using the Activator method as follows:

```c#
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EnvDTE80;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestWindowsApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.14.0");
            DTE2 dte = (DTE2)Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);

            dte.MainWindow.Visible = true;
            dte.UserControl = true;
            SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)dte.MainWindow.HWnd);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

It works great except the process it creates is hidden. If I use Process Explorer's "Find Window's Process" feature I get the error:

---

### Process Explorer Error

### The owning process is devenv.exe (process ID 22196), which is not currently visible in the process list.

### OK

Is there any way to use this method but make the process visible? It makes working with the spawned visual studio a bit harder than if you open it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try File > Show Details for All Processes